# Amazon S3 animated gif - only uploads first frame

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, animated-gif

(I've researched all the similar questions I can find about this on Stackoverflow, and none of them help me to solve my issue)

I can upload a gif to Amazon S3 like this, where request.FileBytes is a byte array:

```
public bool UploadFile(CdnFile request)
{
  var transfer = new TransferUtility(CdnConfig.AccessKey, CdnConfig.SecretKey, ep);
  var uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest();
  uploadRequest.InputStream = new MemoryStream(request.FileBytes);

  var result = transfer.BeginUpload(s3Req2, cb, null);
  transfer.EndUpload(result);
}
```

This works fine for a .jpg, however for an animated .gif, only the 1st frame of the gif is uploaded (if I upload the same gif direct via S3, it works fine). So it must be to do with how I'm streaming or converting the file, however I'm not sure how to find out where the problem occurs.

I create request.FileBytes as follows, where 'imageData' is the raw data for the image (Chrome uses this image data when it displays the animated gif preview that I'm trying to upload to S3, and it animates fine):

```
var data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
var img = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(data));
fileBytes = img.SaveAsGif();

public static byte[] SaveAsGif(this Image img, long quality = 100)
{
    ImageCodecInfo gifEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Gif);

    Encoder myEncoder = Encoder.Quality;

    EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

    EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, quality);
    myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;

    using (MemoryStream msGif = new MemoryStream())
    {
        img.Save(msGif, gifEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
        return msGif.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code works fine for me, perhaps you can adapt it for your use case. I upload a GIF from a local file and it displays/works just fine after uploading:

```
        using (var client = new AmazonS3Client("AKIAI5ZL44fake4442COJA", "4sYnPuA1zMkhghghghghTpX4F5/FUXGDiAKm", RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
        {
            var request = new PutObjectRequest
            {
                BucketName = "bucketname",
                ContentType = "image/gif",
                Key = "test.gif",
                FilePath = @"c:\dev\006.gif"
            };
            var response = client.PutObject(request);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

My SaveAsGif method was the problem, so the issue is something to do with the codec. I can create my request.fileBytes without using the codec like this and it works:

```
var imageStream = new MemoryStream(data);
fileBytes = imageStream.ToArray();
```